# What counts as a "visit" for immigration forms?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, transit

It is often asked in official immigration forms (US) about the countries visited in the past. Do flight connections count in this case, or do they mean exiting the airport/gate area?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is normally considered a visit if you are processed by Customs and Immigration, which you don't usually do on a connecting flight.

Comment: Unless, of course, that connecting flight happens to be in the U.S. or you leave the airport during the connection.

Answer (score 5):

Better safe than sorry. If you claim to have visited a country but never left the airport, what will happen to you? Nothing. They may say "tell me about your visit to X" and you will say "actually I never left the airport, it was a connection" and that's that. No consequences.

But if you leave it off, and they say "well how did you get from A to B?" and you say "I transited through C" and then they say "why didn't you list C on here?" then suddenly you're a person whose answers on the form might not be complete.

I recently had to list ten countries to answer that question. I listed them all. Just do it.